# Add event to Google calendar without showing the calendar

Tags: calendar

Preferable via a widget or app on Windows and Android. There's emailing but it seems inconvenient.

I can't help myself to look at all the other events and feel stress.

Comment: try asking this on http://webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: @einpoklum: It asks for a widget or app recommendation, so it would be off-topic on webapps.SE

Answer (score 1):

I use [If This Then That (IFTTT)](https://ifttt.com/) for this.

You can create a *Recipe* within IFTTT which will add an entry to your Google Calendar.
[image: Calendar Recipe]

Adding a *Do* button to your Android phone provides easy access to this recipe.  Alternatively it can be accessed from Windows or various other means.

Comment: It's a solution. I would however prefer a UX. Remember the milk has a UX and a widget for android but is not syncing to google calendar. How do you suggest I add an event from Windows?

Answer (score 1):

In your browser, type into the universal what-do-you-call-it box something like:

> schedule dentist appointment for tomorrow 4 pm

Hit return.  You will then see

[image: intermediate step of event creation]

At which point you should click on the blue link called "Create event."  The event will be created and here's what will appear next:

[image: completed event creation]

At no point is your entire calendar, or even your agenda for today, displayed.

I experimented with *appt* in place of *appointment* and it emphatically did not work.

(I did my testing in Firefox; I found this trick at https://blog.calendly.com/the-ultimate-google-calendar-guide-90-tips-to-supercharge-productivity-6ee8585a7e07)

Comment: Great answer! best in my opinion

Comment: I did some more testing.  It's quite finicky.  The following did not work: "schedule test appointment for July 1 at 2 pm."  When I wrote "dentist" in place of "test," it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I settled on Rainlendar for Windows, which have hotkey for adding new event. On Android I'm still using IFTTT which is not ideal. Rememberthemilk's widget is ideal but RTM won't sync to gcal.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: [Google Calendar Quick Add Utility for Windows](https://mountwhite.net/en/google-cal-quick-add-software.html)

The developer's description: Quickly create events in your Google Calendar by typing the description in natural language.

I haven't tested this yet.